# Is there anything like numerical variable with labels?

Tags: r

I have a numerical variable with discrete levels, that have a special meaning for me, e.g.

```
-1 'less than zero'
 0 'zero'
 1 'more than zero'
```

I know, that I can convert the variable as factor/ordinal and keep the labels, but then the numerical representation of the variable would be

```
 1 'less than zero'
 2 'zero'
 3 'more than zero'
```

which is useless for me. I cannot afford having two copies of the variable, because of memory constraints (it is a very big data.table).

Is there any standard way of adding text labels to certain levels of the numerical (possibly integer) variable, so that I can get a nice looking frequency tables just like if it was a factor, and simultaneously being able to treat it as the source numerical variable with values untouched?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say the answer to your questions is "no". There's no standard or built-in way of doing what you want.

Because, as you note, factors have positive non-zero integer codes, and integers can't be denoted by label strings in a vector. Not in a "standard" way anyway.

So you will have to do the labelling yourself, in whatever outputs you want to present, manually.

Any tricks like keeping your data (once) as a factor and subtracting a number to get the negative values you need (presumably for your analysis) will make a copy of that data. Keep the numbers, do the analysis, then do replacement with the results (which I presume are tables and plots and so aren't as big as the data).

R also doesn't have an equivalent to the "enumerated type" of many languages, which is one way this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a vector. Would that work?

```
var <- c(-1,0,1)
names(var) <- c("less than zero", "zero", "more than zero")
```

that would give you

```
> var
less than zero           zero more than zero 
            -1              0              1
```

Hope that helps,
Umberto

Comment: In addition to my answer, you could check colnames in the R documentation https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html What do you exactly need to do?

Comment: I need to standardise R's `data.frame`/`data.table` format, so it can be logically interoperable with SAS and SPSS data bases. SPSS has an option to append to each variable a dictionary with labels for any of the levels. Unlike R, SPSS does it *without* modifying the numerical representation of the variable.